# How to invert the color of TextFormField in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I changed my application color. However `TextFormField` have got very invisible.
Are there any way to modify the `TextFormField` as it is better.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LoVe is correct. There are constructors for the TextFormField class that you can use here: [Flutter documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html). Another example:

```
TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Colors.lightBlue[50],
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                hintText: 'What do people call you?',
                labelText: 'Name',
              ),
              onSaved: (String value) {
                // This optional block of code can be used to run
                // code when the user saves the form.
              },
            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change the style and fill color to make it fit with the current theme:

```
TextFormField(
        style: someTextStyle,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintStyle:someTextStyle
          fillColor: someColor,
          filled: true,
        ),
      )
```